# Domain redirect to go daddy shared ip account via IP through an A NAME change

Tags: redirects, dns, ip-address, godaddy, cname

A customers IT department wants to point their domain to a site I've created for them which is hosted on a share GoDaddy account. It's not my primary domain but is a site in a sub directory of its own.  He wants to do a A NAME change at his end and has requested my IP.

However I'm guessing that with a shared IP that the IP alone won't make the redirect work correctly.  It's important that their original domain address appears in the browser 
bar once the redirect takes place.  Do I need to do some king of mapping to guarantee that his redirect finds the correct content in the sub folder?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to add your customers domain by adding a 'addon' domain to your account and use the sub directory you have currently. Shared IP's are not an issue and setting the add-on domain will do the rest once you have got your customer to add the AAA Name Record to the shared IP address. If you plan to host their mail for them then your need them to get them to add MX records or alternatively have them use GoDaddys name servers.

Below is some instructions how to add a addon domain, further assistance should be provided by GoDaddy as thats what your paying them for ;)

> [Adding Addon Domains to Your cPanel Shared Hosting Account](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/8877/adding-addon-domains-to-your-cpanel-shared-hosting-account)
>
> 1. Log in to your Account Manager.
> 2. Click Web Hosting.
> 3. Next to the domain name you want to use, click Launch.
> 4. In the Domains section, click Addon Domains.
> 5. Complete the following fields, and then click Add Domain.
>
>    1. New Domain Name — Enter the domain name you want to use.
>    2. Subdomain/FTP Username — Enter the FTP username you want to use.
>    3. Document Root — Enter the name of a directory you want to create in the home directory. You'll upload the New Domain Name's
>         files to this directory to make its website display.
>    4. Password & Password (Again) — Enter the FTP password you want to use.

Comment: Hi Bybe that is really useful and I understand most of it.  However the site I created was hosted on its own domain.  Do I need to move the files to a totally new folder/sub director and then follow your instructs to just point to that?  Or in your section 2. Can I point to my current domain/its sub directory folder?  I need to make sure that the original domain is the one that appears in the search bar.  Sorry for not fully understanding.  Best regards Stuart

Comment: You should be able to use the current sub folder you have at the moment, but personally I'd setup a new one and use the current one the backup.

Comment: How can I access my Wordpress site it make further changes if it's in a folder with no domain linked to it?  Sorry to be a pain.

Comment: Hi Bybe, To do as you suggested do I, Add Domain then tell it the domain of the web site that is being redirected to me - Then in the next box add the current domain with the folder reference e.g.. www.currentsite/site folder?

Comment: Simply following the instructions as guided above, Document Root = Folder (don't write www. or the domain here). Then you're done. By the way GoDaddy have ok support, they will happily talk you through this process.